# Как объявить сторонний класс используя QtDesigner чтобы использовать его методы?

Tags: c++, qt

Как мне объявить другие классы для моего класса QMainWindow учитывая то что я использую QtDesigner? Я попробовал, но не могу это сделать, потому-что компилятор выдает ошибку С2512 ( нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию) ( здесь ui(new Ui::MainWindow)).

Comment: Ваш вопрос трудно понять. Дизайнер нужен, чтобы виджеты мышкой на форме расставлять. А классы - это уже стезя редактора кода. Попробуйте как-нибудь иначе составить свой вопрос или привести уточнение, что конкретно Вы делали. Возможно последнее поможет понять ход Ваших рассуждений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас нет *своего* класса `QMainWindow`, только его наследники. В Дизайнере вряд ли понадобится что-то в нём менять, а вот в коде Вы можете дополнять этот класс как пожелаете.

Если же Вы хотите создать новое, отдельное окно, то и создавать в IDE нужно по-новой. Выберите `New File` ~> `Qt Designer Form class`, получите какие-нибудь `newwindow.ui`, `newwindow.cpp` и `newwindow.h`, с ними можно будет также полноценно работать.